# relative path to a folder that is out of the public folder in zf2

Tags: zend-framework2

I have an upload folder out of the public folder and I am trying to show an image on an img html tag. To be acccurate create a relative path for the src attribute.

I don't seem to find the way to create a relative path to the image because the basepath() view helper is pointing to the public folder.

I haven't been working with zend framework 2 for too long so my search terms probably weren't very accurate. I did read the oficial documentation about the basepath viewhelper and more than a few question here on stack overflow but nothing.

Thanks in advence for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser can't view files outside of the document root (`public`). You'll either need to move them, symlink to them (from within `public`), or serve the images via. PHP.